# Pandas: Apply agg on two columns at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am migrating some of pySpark code into Pandas and stuck with implementing `collect_set` on two columns. 
pySpark code looks like this:

`df_collect = df.groupBy('col1').agg(collect_set('col2').alias('Col2Arr'), collect_set('col3').alias('Col3Arr'))`

I can easily implement for one of the columns by calling `lambda` function on `agg` but can't do it on two columns at the same time:

`df_collect = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg({'Col2Arr': lambda x: set(x)})`

I tried:

`df.groupby('col1').agg(Col2Arr = lambda x: set(x['col2']), Col3Arr = lambda x: set(x['col3']))`

and

```
def count_set(x):
    d = {}
    d['Col2Arr'] = lambda a: set(a['col2'])
    d['Col3Arr'] = lambda a: set(a['col3'])
    return pd.Series(d, index=['Col2Arr', 'Col3Arr'])

df.groupby('col1').apply(count_set)
```

Nothing seem to work. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: `df2.groupby("col1")[['col2','col3']].agg(set).reset_index()` ?

Comment: @anky Your answers worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're looking for, as [@anky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152914/pandas-apply-agg-on-two-columns-at-a-time#comment120453364_68152914) suggests, a standard [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) with selecting the desired columns may work:

```
df_collect = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)[['col2', 'col3']].agg(set)
```

`df_collect`:

```
   col1                         col2                         col3
0     1           {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
1     2  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}     {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
2     3              {2, 3, 6, 7, 8}        {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
3     4     {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}        {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
4     5           {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}           {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9}
5     6              {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}           {1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9}
6     7        {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}           {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
7     8        {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
8     9           {1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}              {2, 4, 5, 6, 9}
```

Or, for something more similar to the way `PySpark` looks, use [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to incorporate aliasing, column selection, and separate aggregation options:

```
df_collect = (
    df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)
        .agg(Col2Arr=('col2', set), Col3Arr=('col3', set))
)
```

`df_collect`:

```
   col1                      Col2Arr                      Col3Arr
0     1           {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9}        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
1     2  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}     {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
2     3              {2, 3, 6, 7, 8}        {2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
3     4     {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}        {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
4     5           {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}           {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9}
5     6              {2, 3, 5, 6, 7}           {1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9}
6     7        {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}           {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
7     8        {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
8     9           {1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9}              {2, 4, 5, 6, 9}
```

---

Sample data used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (100, 3)),
                  columns=[1, 2, 3]).add_prefix('col')
```

`df.head(10)`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     4     7     7
1     1     9     5
2     8     1     1
3     8     2     6
4     8     1     2
5     5     7     3
6     2     3     8
7     1     6     1
8     1     5     5
9     4     3     5
```